# Access to virtual machine on vmware

Tags: vmware

I have a virtual machine (VMware) running Windows 7 Ultimate, there is no firewall on the machine.
I can remote desktop to it, 
I can successfully ping it from my development machine, and I can successfully ping my development machine from it.
The virtual machine appears in explorer under Network, but if I click on it, it says that windows cant communicate with the device or resource, same goes for trying to access it using UNC notation (\\servername) and even UNC using ip address (\\xxx-xxx-xxx)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows UNC syntax for a networked machine should be `\\<name>` or `\\<ip>`.

Edit:
You'll only be able to access *shared* folders over Microsoft Windows Network (aka SMB). You probably haven't set up shared folders. Read this: [VMWare Workstation 4: Using Shared Folders](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html)

Comment: Hi, for some reason when I posted, the stackoverflow site took out the extra slashes. I did try with the notation you use above. Any other ideas?